# Can't align angle values with siunitx in table

Tags: tables, siunitx, german

I'm having trouble aligning angle values in my document with siunitx. The numbers are only aligned properly if I don't use the `\ang{}` command from siunitx. I made a small, minimum working example that shows the issue:

[image]

```
\documentclass[
    12pt,                                   
    DIV=12,                                 
    paper=A4,                                                       
    parskip=half,                                           
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{booktabs}                       
\usepackage{tabularx}                       

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{locale = DE}


\begin{document}
    
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Align the following numbers}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{S[table-format=+2.2]}
        \toprule
        \textbf{Values} \\
        \midrule
        \ang{70,50}     \\
        \ang{40,50}     \\
        \ang{20,50}     \\
        \ang{-4,40}     \\
        \ang{0,50}      \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \label{tab:Test1}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h]
    \caption{Align the following numbers}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{S[table-format=+2.2]}
        \toprule
        \textbf{Values} \\
        \midrule
        70,50           \\
        40,50           \\
        20,50           \\
        -4,40           \\
         0,50           \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \label{tab:Test2}
\end{table}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage[locale = DE]{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ @{} S[table-format = -1.2 \unit{\degree},
                       table-align-text-after = false] @{} }
  \toprule
  {\textbf{Values}} \\
  \midrule
  70,50 \unit{\degree} \\
  40,50 \unit{\degree} \\
  20,50 \unit{\degree} \\
  -4,40 \unit{\degree} \\
   0,5  \unit{\degree} \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is what i was looking for. Thank you very much!

Comment: I just noticed a problem with this solution that becomes visible if you use another unit. The space between the numeric value and the unit is not added automatically. You can fix this manually if you insert a \thinspace between the numeric value and the unit.

Comment: @mab0189 If the unit is common to all the entries, it should be in the column header; if the values have different units, they shouldn't be aligned at the decimal separator.

Comment: @egreg This is a valid remark, but I would like to convince myself of the various possibilities.